# How to move migration to another project on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Hello i have an existing project on laravel and i want to move migrations files to another project .  do i go to copy and paste it on the new project or have other way to do it with  command-line.

Best regards

Comment: You can copy past

Comment: Feel free to copy the file ! Then run `php artisan migrate` and it will just work (as far as the class is correct, of course)

Answer (score 3):

When you use the command `php artisan make:migration` the timestamps will be included in the name file. If you copy and paste the migration file into your new project you should change that name, otherwise you may have problems because migrations run on the chronological order.

So, i think the best approach here is to use the command `php artisan make:migration`in your new project and copy your code from the old migration to this new one.

> The new migration will be placed in your database/migrations directory. Each migration file name contains a timestamp which allows Laravel to determine the order of the migrations.

You can do this in both ways, but make sure you correct the timestamps in the name file if you go for the first option